# Android- Nested Fragments Implementation with TabViewer

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragments

I have this activity that uses tabs, but I am not sure how to include nested fragments in just one tab.

I wanted to achieve this:

```
Tab 1
--Fragment A --> Fragment B
```

**From the Docu**

> To nest a fragment, simply call getChildFragmentManager() on the
>   Fragment in which you want to add a fragment. This returns a
>   FragmentManager that you can use like you normally do from the
>   top-level activity to create fragment transactions. For example,
>   here’s some code that adds a fragment from within an existing Fragment
>   class:

```
Fragment videoFragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.video_fragment, videoFragment).commit();
```

**SampleTabsWithIcons**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.example.tabwithicon.R;
import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter;
import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator;

public class SampleTabsWithIcons extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Calendar", "Camera", "Alarms", "Location" };
    private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
            R.drawable.perm_group_calendar,
            R.drawable.perm_group_camera,
            R.drawable.perm_group_device_alarms,
            R.drawable.perm_group_location,
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_tabs_with_icons);

        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {
        public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fragments: "+CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fragments Title: "+CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
        }

        @Override public int getIconResId(int index) {

          return ICONS[index];
        }

      @Override
        public int getCount() {
          return CONTENT.length;
        }
    }
}
```

**TestFragment**

```
public final class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";

    public static TestFragment newInstance(String content) {
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            builder.append(content).append(" ");
        }
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        fragment.mContent = builder.toString();

        return fragment;
    }

    private String mContent = "???";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
            mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text.setText(mContent);
        text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);


        inflater = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_inside_activity, null);

        //LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(text);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
    }
}
```

**activity_sample_tabs_with_icons**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
07-12 14:33:30.685: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:30.685: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:31.984: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:31.984: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:33.279: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:33.280: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:34.707: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:34.709: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:34.710: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:34.711: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:34.806: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:34.807: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:34.830: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:34.832: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:36.579: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:36.580: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:36.583: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:36.584: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:36.704: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:36.709: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:36.797: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:36.798: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:37.071: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:33:37.071: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18607): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-12 14:37:21.166: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19086): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself, I have to make sure that I am in the right page to put the nested fragments. Using the `switch`, I was able to nest a fragment. In `LaunchpadSectionFragment()` extends a fragments, inside this fragment calls the `getChildFragmentManager()` to start the nesting of another fragments inside `LaunchpadSectionFragment`.

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:

                return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();
}
```

**Nesting:**

```
Fragment videoFragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
Fragment videoFragment2 = new VideoPlayerFragment2();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.video_fragment, videoFragment);
transaction.add(R.id.video_fragment2, videoFragment2);
transaction.commit()
```